# iOS 8 Push notification does not work on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have an application as general I want to use APN with iOS Push notification. My push notification compatible with ios 8 and less. Push notification permission dialog properly works when I launch on simulator.  But when launched in real device it says;

> "Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received
>   permission from the user to badge the application"

**AppDelegate**

```
[[NotificationManager sharedInstance] requestPushNotificationIfNeeded];
```

**NotificationManager - requestPushNotificationIfNeeded**

```
// Refresh the token.
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        // iOS 8 Notification
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    }
    else {
        // Less then iOS 8
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }
#else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
#endif
```

**App Delegate methods**

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:   (UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    TRACE(@"Delegate did");
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    // Using parse.com save push notification token
}
```

**Question**

What's wrong with this code? I'm trying for days but in vain. Could you please guide me about this error ? What's wrong or am I missing something neccessary? Thank you so much.

---

By the way I logged out delegate methods only register **UIUserNotificationTypeAlert** 
Like so;

```
Delegate didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: <UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x17422e2c0; types: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);>
```

Comment: what is your device iOS Version?

Comment: @TENSRI app now running on iOS 8.2

Comment: As I know everything is fine and can you try to delete the app and reinstall or clean the build in the project ....

Comment: have you enable the remote notifications in the Project Capabilities??

Comment: @kayzersoze Can you paste here you push notification delegation methods?

Comment: @Asaf Actually, I did not do anything special in delegate methods. :/

Comment: @kayzersoze so you have this method: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} ?

Comment: @TENSRI I did it again and again. But still same.

Comment: @Asaf This delegate method already exist in project :/

Comment: Did your app asked for the permission for push notifications when you first started it ?

Comment: @AhsanEbrahim Yes but only when launched simulator. When launcing real device it didn't ask anything only says  "Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your app doesnt have proper `permissions` to generate `push notifications`.
As per the apple's recommendation in this case which I once had to follow too. Follow these steps:
1) Unistall the app, then restart your phone.
2) Go to settings -> date and time and set the date to atleast 1 day ahead the current date.
3) Again restart your device.
4) Now go to settings and bring the time back to normal.
5) Restart the device.
6) Now install the app and it should ask you for push notifications' permissions. Incase if it still does not asks for the permissions, repeat the above step again but after step 4 rather than restarting just install the app then restart and you'll be good to go.
I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you. But it does not solve my problem :/ This error makes me CRY!

Comment: In order to get the push notifications you must first get the permission from the user. If the permission is not being asked at the first run of the Application's launch then you must try for getting the permissions first.

Comment: I know these steps, It works perfectly on simulator but in case when launched real device it did not ask anything. When I want to run the app on simulator firstly I clicked `iOS Simulator` menu where is top left corner afterwards clicked `Reset Contents and Settings...` it's ok. Notification works. But when I comes in real device. Boom nothing.

Comment: In your opinion I should try these steps too ? https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT201274

Comment: This might make the app work as the device will be totally new but it isnt recommended as you won't be doing this everytime you create/install/modify an app. I know its alot problematic as i myself was stuck in the same problem that the notifications were totally fine it was just the permissions that was causing this trouble. Try these steps again or i'll give you a link from apple's support you can try those quick steps too.. These work, patiently try.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

in this documentation find the heading `Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS` and try those quick steps i hope these work for you, as they did for me after a couple of tries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74830/discussion-between-kayzer-soze-and-ahsan-ebrahim).